# My javaFX displaying blank output.. what to do?

Tags: java, javafx

I am using my JavaFX in eclipse and I am new this . I have setup the JavaFX in the eclipse. at first I can run my desire output. However when I try to rerun it again The output display is blank

I have check all the things that suppose to do but still no changes and I do not know where is the problem right now. Please do help me . I would appreciate it a lot

Here is my code.

Main.java:

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

ButtonPane.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        HBox horizontalPane = new HBox();
        horizontalPane.setSpacing(10);
        horizontalPane.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        
        Button button1 = new Button("Button 1");
        Button button2 = new Button("Button 2");
        Button button3 = new Button("Button 3");
        Button button4 = new Button("Button 4");
        Button button5 = new Button("Button 5");
        Button button6 = new Button("Button 6");

        
        horizontalPane.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6);

        
        Scene scene = new Scene(horizontalPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Activity1");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUODr.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more information including, but not necessarily limited to, Java version, JavaFX version, Eclipse version, build tool version (if any), operating system name and version, architecture (e.g., x64, aarch64, etc.), and a [mre] (including how exactly you run the program) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I don't see a ButtonPane instantiated anywhere. You might need to add a one to your BorderPane.

Comment: It's not logical to have two classes extend `Application`.

Comment: As noted, it doesn't make sense for a JavaFX application to have more than one `Application` subclass (possibly unless you're doing something unusually complex). And if `Main` is the class you're launching, then a blank screen is expected, as you set the root of the scene to a childless `BorderPane`.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 start methods you should only have one , in that case you should run each file independently to see the output.
make sure to configure your run configuration to run the application as a JavaFX application.
it's tiring to hard code everything by hand try using Scenebuilder it will help you gain so much time or write raw fxml still easier, when you create fxml you will you blocks of code like this to display  each file.

```
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("home.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,Color.BLACK);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("src/gui/css/style.css");
        primaryStage.setTitle("s'inscrire!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: thank you guys.. I have succeed .. and it is true that it is my code that are the problem not the  application